# Simple div-sorting with jquery not working

Tags: jquery, sorting

On jsfiddle everything works perfectly, but not on the "web"

I can move **1** under **2**, but not **1** under **3** (on "web")

Live [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolomonili/pthk2r5x/) (on jsfiddle everything works perfectly)

### html

```
<div class="parent">

    <div id="parent_child1"> 
        <span class="title">1</span>
         <span class="down" onclick="down('parent_child1')">down</span>
         <span class="up" onclick="up('parent_child1')">up</span>
    </div>

    <div id="parent_child2"> 
        <span class="title">2</span>
         <span class="down" onclick="down('parent_child2')">down</span>
         <span class="up" onclick="up('parent_child2')">up</span>
    </div>

    <div id="parent_child3"> 
        <span class="title">3</span>
         <span class="down" onclick="down('parent_child3')">down</span>
         <span class="up" onclick="up('parent_child3')">up</span>
    </div>

    <div id="parent_child4"> 
        <span class="title">4</span>
         <span class="down" onclick="down('parent_child4')">down</span>
         <span class="up" onclick="up('parent_child4')">up</span>
    </div>


</div>
```

### javascript

```
function down(id) {

    var nextDiv = $("#"+id).next()[0].id;
    $("#"+nextDiv).after($("#"+id));

}

function up(id) {

    var nextDiv = $("#"+id).prev()[0].id;
    $("#"+nextDiv).before($("#"+id));

}
```

### css

```
.parent {
    width:300px;
}
.parent > div {
    width:230px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    float:left;
}
.parent div span.title {
    width:130px;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
}
.parent div span.down {
    text-align:center;
    width:50px;
    height:30px;
    background:green;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.parent div span.up {
    text-align:center;
    width:50px;
    height:30px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Linking to a fiddle that works perfectly fine and telling us it somwhow doesn't work "on the web" doesn't really help us help you ?

Comment: I know, but I do not know how to explain the problem. at least I posted the code

Comment: Adding functions to `$(document).ready()`? Don't do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try something like this, maybe this works also for your web:

http://jsfiddle.net/nzx2bz3r/

```
function down(obj) {
    $(obj).parent().next().after($(obj).parent())
}

function up(id) {
     $(obj).parent().prev().before($(obj).parent())
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="parent_child1"> 
    <span class="title">1</span>
    <span class="down" onclick="down(this)">down</span>
    <span class="up" onclick="up(this)">up</span>
</div>
```